# Enum based Combobox

Tags: java, enums, vaadin

```
cmbSablonSecim = new ComboBox<>();
cmbSablonSecim.setItems(EnumSablonSecim.values());
```

My combo box --> TUMU,GRAFIK,DAGILIM

I want fill my combobox with Enum->islemAdi

Combobox --> Tümü,Grafik,Dağılım (Enum->islemAdi)

```
public enum EnumSablonSecim {
    TUMU(0, "Tümü"),
    GRAFIK(1, "Grafik"),
    DAGILIM(2, "Dağılım")
    ;

    private final Integer islemKodu;
    private final String islemAdi;

    private EnumSablonSecim(Integer islemKodu, String islemAdi) {
        this.islemKodu = islemKodu;
        this.islemAdi = islemAdi;
    }

    public Integer getIslemKodu() {
        return islemKodu;
    }

    public String getIslemAdi() {
        ResourceBundle messages = I18n.getInstance(this.getClass());
        if (messages.containsKey(islemAdi)) {
            return messages.getString(islemAdi);    
        } else {
            return islemAdi;
        }
    }

    public static EnumSablonSecim get(Integer islemKodu) {
        for (EnumSablonSecim enumSablonSecim : EnumSablonSecim.values()) {
            if (enumSablonSecim.islemKodu == islemKodu) {
                return enumSablonSecim;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

My combobox must return (islemAdi).is it possible or not? Thank you...

Comment: I don't realy understand your question, Tümü,Grafik,Dağılım is Enum type but islemAdi is a String right ?
Do you want these 4 values in your comboBox ?
if yes, you can create an array list for exemple and add it as values of your Combobox

Comment: Yes.is it possible without array (with directly ENUM?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `ComboBox::setItemLabelGenerator`

Are you asking if you can show the `islemAdi` field as the label in the combo box?

You can specify code to generate a label used for displaying each item in your enum. Call [`ComboBox::setItemLabelGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.7/com/vaadin/flow/component/combobox/ComboBox.html#setItemLabelGenerator-com.vaadin.flow.component.ItemLabelGenerator-). Pass a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) for your getter. Vaadin then calls this method as needed to display each item.

```
cmbSablonSecim.setItemLabelGenerator(EnumSablonSecim::getIslemAdi);
```

See [*Showing a List of Data with Data Providers*](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/binding-data/tutorial-flow-data-provider.html) in the manual.

Comment: Further explanation: The ComboBox will still be of Type `ComboBox<EnumSablonSecim>` and not `ComboBox<String>`, but you can choose how each item is represented with `setItemLabelGenerator(..)`. You still set the items with the same line that OP has written in the question: `cmbSablonSecim.setItems(EnumSablonSecim.values());`. No need for creating an array of Strings.